# Add alias to the column name where have postfix in column name in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there any possible way I can find and set the column name by giving alias

**for example**

I have a sql queries which contain 4 column name fields. 3 fields are common in all the queries

id, name, field

and there is another field which column name get change every time but the only common thing in that field it has a postfix as `__type`

so my sql query looks like this

```
SELECT * from table_name

id, name, field, system_data__value
```

is there any possible way I can add alias to the name where I found `__type` as type

so if I run my queries then it look like this

```
SELECT * from table_name

id, name, field, type
```

Comment: You need to provide details on how you are getting that column name changed and then this forum can help you with details.

Comment: Hi @sankar there is a lot of code behind this and I just wanted to know if this can be possible and if this can be possible then how can I achieve this? :)

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: phpMyAdmin @jarlh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use UNION ALL for to set the aliases to the columns posessionally.

You must know some value which cannot present in some column (`id = -1` in shown code) for fake row removing.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT -1 id, NULL name, NULL field, NULL alias_for_column_4
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * from table_name  -- returns id, name, field, system_data__value
    ) subquery
WHERE id > 0                  -- removes fake row
```

It is possible that the values in fake subquery needs in explicit CAST() calls for correct datatype of the output columns setting.